# отправка сообщения пользователю в указанное им время python telebot

Tags: python, telebot

делаю телеграм бота, суть которого в том, что бот запрашивает у пользователя день, час и минуту, и по наступлению указанных данных бот отправляет пользователю сообщение. Может кто-нибудь показать как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Подобное делал для python-telegram-bot: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/33456ec63dc6be4bc06652e953c72731246c0237/telegram_bot_examples/reminder . Там используется база данных

Comment: готовых решений не знаю, может кто подскажет. Придумать можно сколь угодно. Как пример - Сохранять в БД задачи с сообщением, временем отправки и признаком 'выполнено'. Отдельный микросервис должен мониторить раз n секунд/минут/дней (в зависимости от того, какую погрешность допускаете)  и отправлять.